# Iterate through specific tags in python

Tags: python

I want to extract text from the website and the format is like this:

```
<a href="#N44">Avalon</a>
<a href="#N36">Avondale</a>
<a href="#N4">Bacon Park Area</a>
```

How do I just select those 'a' tags with href="#N" because there are several more?

I tried creating a list to iterate through but when I try the code, it selects only one element.

```
loc= ['#N0', '#N1', '#N2', '#N3', '#N4', '#N5'.....'#N100']

for i in loc:
    name=soup.find('a', attrs={'href':i})    
print(name)
```

I get

```
<a href="#N44">Avalon</a>
```

not

```
<a href="#N44">Avalon</a>
<a href="#N36">Avondale</a>
<a href="#N4">Bacon Park Area</a
```

How about just?

```
Avalon
Avondale
Bacon Park Area
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're just overwriting the value each time you iterate.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the items, but not putting them anywhere. So when you are done with your loop all that's left in `name` is the last item.

You can put them in a list like below, and access the `.text` attribute to get just the name from the tag:

```
names = []

for i in loc:
    names.append(soup.find('a',attrs={'href':i}).text)
```

Result:

```
In [15]: names
Out[15]: ['Bacon Park Area', 'Avondale', 'Avalon']
```

---

If you want to leave out the first list's creation you can just do:

```
import re

names = [tag.text for tag in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile(r'#N\d+'))]
```

In a regular expression, the `\d` means digit and the `+` means one or more instances of.

Comment: Thank you!  How about if I don't want to create the list and just select any href that has a #N with a number i.e. href="#N44" or href="#N45"?

Comment: @user3746017: you're welcome! Please see edit for a way to avoid the first list's creation.

Comment: This works great! Thanks for explaining \d and + in reg expression to a beginner like me. I really thought I had to keep the format attrs={'href':i} syntax but replacing with re.compile is simpler.